# How to configure nginx with multiple docker-compose.yml files?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

If I want to setup nginx with my docker containers, one option is to setup the nginx instance in my `docker-compose.yml`, and link the nginx container to all application containers.

The drawback of this approach, however, is that the `docker-compose.yml` becomes server-level, since only one nginx container can expose ports 80/443 to the internet.

I'm interested in being able to define several `docker-compose.yml` files on the same server, but still easily expose the public-facing containers in each compose file via a single server-specific nginx container.

I feel this should be pretty easy, but I haven't been able to find a good resource or example for this.

Comment: Do you want to have one docker-compose.yml for NGINX, one for containers set #1, another one for containers set #2 etc, so you could start and stop some container sets without affecting others?

Comment: Exactly. So even though they exist on separate networks, NGINX reverse proxies the application container within. Or maybe NGINX exists on the default network without compose - that's not so important.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First, you need to create a network for nginx and the proxied containers:

```
docker network create nginx_network
```

Next, configure the nginx container in a compose file like this:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: your_nginx_image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - nginx_network
networks:
  nginx_network:
    external: true
```

After that you can run proxied containers:

```
services:
  webapp1:
    image: ...
    container_name: mywebapp1
    networks:
      - nginx_network      # proxy and app must be in same network
      - webapp1_db_network # you can use additional networks for some stuff
  database:
    image: ...
    networks:
      - webapp1_db_network
networks:
  nginx_network:
    external: true
  webapp1_db_network: ~ # this network won't be accessible from outside
```

Also, to make this work you need to configure your nginx properly:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_app.example.com;
    
    # Docker DNS
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
  
    location / {
        # hack to prevent nginx to resolve container's host on start up
        set $docker_host "mywebapp1";
        proxy_pass http://$docker_host:8080;
    }
}
```

You need to tell nginx to use Docker's DNS, so it will be able to access containers by their names.

But note that if you run the nginx container before the others, then nginx will try to resolve another container's host and fail, because the other containers are not running yet. You can use a hack with placing the host into a variable. With this hack, nginx won't try to resolve host until receiving a request.

With this combination you can have nginx always up, while starting and stopping proxied applications independently.

**Update:**

If you want a more dynamic solution, you can modify the nginx config as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    
    # define server_name with regexp which will read subdomain into variable
    server_name ~^(?<webapp>.+)\.example\.com;

    location / {
        # use variable from regexp to pass request to desired container
        proxy_pass http://$webapp:8080;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, a request to webapp1.example.com will be passed to container "webapp1", webapp2.example.com to "webapp2" etc. You only need to add DNS records and run app containers with right name.

Comment: Hm, the thing about this solution is that the compose file for each of the apps would need to reference that server specific setup. That doesn't seem very dynamic. What if we assume I can't edit the app compose files, but only control when / how they are executed - and also the NGINX compose file. Would that be doable?

Comment: It's very important not to add a slash at the end of  `proxy_pass http://$docker_host`, if you added it you will get always the index file for every request.  Wrong mapping `proxy_pass http://$docker_host/`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great, but since I am in the trenches with this right now I'm going to expand upon it with my debugging steps in hopes it helps someone (myself in the future?)

Docker-compose projects often use nginx as reverse-proxy to route http traffic to the other docker services. nginx was a service in my `projectfolder/docker-compose.yml` which was connected to two docker networks.

One was the default network created when I used docker-compose up on `projectfolder/docker-compose.yml` (It is named `projectfolder_default` and services connect to it by default UNLESS you have a `networks` property for your service with another network, then make sure you add  `- default` to the list). When I ran `docker network ls` I saw `projectfolder_default` in the list and when I ran `docker network inspect projectfolder_default` I saw the nginx container, so everything was good.

The other was a network called `my_custom_network` that I set up myself. I had a startup script that created it if it did not exist using https://stackoverflow.com/a/53052379/13815107 I needed it in order to talk to the `web` service in `otherproject/docker-compose.yml`. I had correctly added `my_custom_network` to:

- `nginx` service's networks list of `projectfolder/docker-compose.yml`
- bottom of `projectfolder/docker-compose.yml`
- `web` service's networks in `otherproject/docker-compose.yml`
- bottom of `otherproject/docker-compose.yml`

The network showed up and had the right containers using `docker network ls` and `docker network inspect my_custom_network`

However, I assumed that proxy_pass to http://web in my server.conf would map to the docker service `web.projectfolder_default`. I was mistaken. To test this I opened shell on the nginx container (`docker exec -it nginx sh`). When I used `ping web` (may need to `apt-get update`, `apt-get install iputils-ping`) it succeeded, but it printed a url with `my_custom_network` which is how I figured out the mistake.

Update: I tried using `http://web.my_custom_network` in `server.conf.template` and it routed great, but my webapp (Django-based) choked on underscores in the url. I renamed web to web2 in `otherproject/docker-compose.yml` and then used something like `docker stop otherproject_web` and `docker rm otherproject_web` to get rid of the bad one.

projectfolder/docker-compose.yml

```
  services:
    # http://web did NOT map to this service!! Use http://web.main_default or change the names
    web:
      ... 
    nginx:
        ...
      links:
        - web
      networks:
        - default
        - my_custom_network
    ...
  networks:
    - my_custom_network
      external: true
```

otherproject/docker-compose.yml

```
  services:
    # http://web connected to this service instead. You could use http://web.my_custom_network to call it out instead
    web:
      ... 
      networks:
        - default
        - my_custom_network
    ...
  networks:
    - my_custom_network
      external: true
```

projectfolder/.../nginx/server.conf.template (next to Dockerfile)
...

```
server {

    ...

    location /auth {
        internal;
        # This routed to wrong 'web'
        proxy_pass              http://web:9001;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    }

    location / {
        alias /data/dist/;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /robots.txt;
    }

    # Project Folder backend
    location ~ ^/(api|login|logout)/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        # This routed to wrong 'web'
        proxy_pass http://web:9001;
    }

    # Other project UI
    location /other-project {
        alias /data/other-project-client/dist/;
    }

    # Other project Django server
    location ~ ^/other-project/(rest)/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        # nginx will route, but won't work some frameworks like django (it doesn't like underscores)
        # I would rename this web2 in yml and use http://web2
        proxy_pass http://web.my_custom_network:8000;
    }
}
```