# Docker Compose networks: create if not exists across multiple files and service definitions?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Docker Compose here. I'm looking at the [Docker networking guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and trying to understand how to perform the equivalent of a "`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`" with a Docker network. Meaning, in SQL, you can usually tell the RDBMS to create a table **if** it doesn't already exist.

Here, from inside a Docker Compose file, I want to tell Docker to create a network if it doesn't already exist, and then connect my services (containers) to it.

Is this possible to do? Ideally it could be flexible such that I could have several different Docker Compose files (`docker-compose-a.yml`, `docker-compose-b.yml` and `docker-compose-c.yml`), and all of them defined various services (containers), but all of them were configured to create (unless already created previously) and use the same "`fizzbuzz`" network.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker create network should ignore existing network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643466/docker-create-network-should-ignore-existing-network)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way at the moment to create network if does not exist.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643466/docker-create-network-should-ignore-existing-network/53052379).

**Update 1**

As you said in comments, you can add this to your `docker-compose` files (each one) in order to be in the same network.

First of all create a network by this command:

```
docker network create NAME
```

Then add this to `docker-compose` files:

```
// from here to next comment is your docker-compose current status
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: some
// end here your current
// here is the part you should add for network
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: NAME
```

Note that before running `docker-compose up -d`, you should create the network or you'll get network does not exist error.

Comment: Thanks @Saeed (+1) so if I have multiple Docker Compose files, how do I get them to all use the same network so their defined services can talk to one another?