# Multiple apps (microservices) and one proxy (nginx) docker-compose configuration/architecture

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Having the following architecture:

- Microservice 1 + DB (microservice1/docker-compose.yml)
- Microservice 2 + DB (microservice2/docker-compose.yml)
- Proxy (proxy/docker-compose.yml)

Which of the following options would be the best to deploy in the production environment?

1. Docker Compose Overriding. Have a docker-compose for each microservice and another docker-compose for the proxy. When the production deployment is done, all the docker-compose would be merged to create only one (with `docker-compose -f microservice1/docker-compose.yml -f microservice2/docker-compose.yml -f proxy/docker-compose.yml up`. In this way, the proxy container, for example nginx, would have access to microservices to be able to redirect to one or the other depending on the request.
2. Shared external network. Have a docker-compose for each microservice and another docker-compose for the proxy. First, an external network would have to be created to link the proxy container with microservices.`docker network create nginx_network`. Then, in each docker-compose file, this network should be referenced in the necessary containers so that the proxy has visibility of the microservices and thus be able to use them in the configuration. An example is in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081535/6112286.

The first option is simple, but offers little felxibility when configuring many microservices or applications, since all docker-compose of all applications would need to be merged to generate the final configuration. The second option uses networks, which are a fundamental pillar of Docker. On the other hand, you don't need all docker-compose to be merged.

Of these two options, given the scenario of having several microservices and needing a single proxy to configure access, which would be the best? Why?

Tnahks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third approach, for example documented in https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php and https://github.com/Einsteinish/Docker-compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-II/. The gist of it is to have the proxy join all the other networks. Thus, you can keep the other compose files, possibly from a software distribution, unmodified.

## docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./
    networks:
      - microservice1
      - microservice2
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

networks:
  microservice1:
    external:
      name: microservice1_default
  microservice2:
    external:
      name: microservice2_default
```

## Proxy configuration

The proxy will refer to the hosts by their names `microservice1_app_1` and `microservice2_app_1`, assuming the services are called `app` in directories `microservice1` and `microservice2`.

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose is designed to orchestrate multiple containers in one single file. I do not know the content of your docker-compose files but the right way is to write one single `docker-compose.yml` that could contains:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  microservice1_app:
    image: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
      - service1_app
      - service1_db

  microservice1_db:
    image: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
      - service1_db

  microservice2_app:
    image: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
      - service2_app
      - service2_db

  microservice2_db:
    image: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
      - service2_db

  nginx:
    image: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
      - default
      - service1_app
      - service2_app

volumes:
...

networks:
  service1_app:
  service1_db:
  service2_app:
  service2_db:
  default:
    name: proxy_frontend
    driver: bridge
```

In this way `nginx` container is able to communicate with `microservice1_app` container through `microservice1_app` hostname. If other hostnames are needed, it can be configured with `aliases` subsection within services `networks` section.

**Security Bonus**
In the above configuration, `microservice1_db` is only visible by `microservice1_app` (same for `microservice2`) and `nginx` is only able to see `microservice1_app` and `microservice2_app` and is reachable from outside of Docker (`bridge` mode)